# WPF MVVM: How to enable/disable buttons in ListBox if I'm using a DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, mvvm, listbox, command, datatemplate

I have a WPF/MVVM app with a `ListBox` which displays data through a `DataTemplate`. I managed to change the selected item in the `ListBox` when pressing a button so the `CommandParameter` is linked to the `ListBox`'s `SelectedItem`, but I cannot get the buttons to be enabled/disabled correctly in the same way. For example, if I have 2 items and the button should be enabled in one and disabled in the other, when I select an element BOTH buttons have the same state, and they BOTH change state when I select another item.

I am using a `RelayCommand` as used in many MVVM Frameworks.

Here is my XAML (removed "not interesting" parts):

```
<UserControl.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Button Content="Something" Name="EnabledDisabledButton" Click="Button_Click"
                            Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.SomeCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
            </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>


    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="ContainerStyle">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" />
    </Style>

</UserControl.Resources>

   <ListBox x:Name="myListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementList}"
             IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContainerStyle}"/>
```

I tried to pass the `SelectedItem` as a parameter to the `RelayCommand`'s `CanExecute` method, but  the result was the same as before.

Is there a way to pass the actual `ListBoxItem` in which the button "lives in" as a parameter to the command, so each one will be processed separately by the `CanExecute` method? Would it work if I got this? (right now I am handling the `Click` event to select the correct item in the list before executing the command).

In my `CanExecute` method I am evaluating some property of the `SelectedItem` in order to enable/disable the corresponding button. An alternative would be to evaluate this property for all elements, but I cannot think of a way to do it inside the `ViewModel`, and then communicate to the view the result (if it is even possible while using a `DataTemplate` for the items).

Thanks for your input, regards!

Comment: what? I don't understand. What do you need the selected Item for? also, why does the button have a click handler? Why not just `CommandParameter="{Binding}"`?

Comment: You use strange and difficult bindings. I would rather add the `SomeCommand` property to each item. Also you don't need command parameters at all. If each item is a view model, they can have a reference to the parent view model and call its methods.

Comment: @HighCore the button has a Click handler because the button inside the listbox item handles the click event, so when you click the button on an unselected element, the list changes the focus to that element befor executing its command. Regarding the binding, you ar totally right, I just got caught up in my own mess.

Comment: @vorrtex, I'll think about your suggestion, it is a possibility to solve this indeed (even if I am working with a VM for the whole list of items, I don't use a VM to wrap each one of them). Thank you both for the input.

Comment: @HighCore please post your comment as an answer for me to approve it, when I changed the CommandParameter binding as you suggested I got to get it working by passing it to the RelayCommand and checking on one of the object's properties. Thank you very much, you've been helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting My comment into an answer:

Why not just `CommandParameter="{Binding}"`?

Answer (score 1):

You mention "MVVM" in the question, but it seems you use the MVVM way to your full advantage.

I would not have a Button_Click event in the style at all. That is because it is in fact a style, which per definition could be changed to another style which does not have the same event, which again will make the application stop working as wanted if you choose to have a style-based app in the future.
A rule I use is that a style is a style. A style has to do with the UI and "looks" of the app.
Functionality should be separate from the UI. The programmer can define the Command, and the designer can decide how the user will use that in the best way.

That's exactly where the code separation from the MVVM pattern cames into grip.
To separate the "looks" and user behavior and the app's logic.
Like...it should not matter to the model if a command fires from a button, a menu, a datacontext or a key stroke.

If this particular problem was handled to ME, I would solve it by having a HOLDER-class.
This is a class (DependencyObject which implements INotifyPropertyChanged) that holds a ICommand property as well as the "row" that will be displayed in the various rows in the ListBox.

The ICommand property will be bound to the Button, having the row (class) itself as CommandParameter to the call.
Then the actual row would be used in the ItemTemplate on the ListBox, with Bindings to different elements (proprty with or withouy Converters) to make whatever desired display available.

I hope I explained good enough...
Feel free to ask more if you want more details to my solution alternative.

Comment: Thank you for your input, but I already solved it based on HighCore comment. Regarding the click event, it is a solution I found to get the listboxitem to get selected when I click on the item's button, because otherwise the button handles the click and the element never gets selected, leading to other problem (at least with my current architechture).